# JacobianMatrix Command Not Working Properly

Tags: vector-calculus

This is what I get when using the command:

```
In[1]: a = {x1^2 + 5 + 6*x2, x1 - x2}
In[2]: b = {x1^4 + x2, x1 + 4*x2^2}
In[3]: JacobianMatrix[a, b] // MatrixForm
Out[3]: JacobianMatrix[{5 + x1^2 + 6 x2, x1 - x2}, {x1^4 + x2, x1 + 4 x2^2}]
```

Any help getting this to properly work?

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{\partial(f,g)}{\partial(h,k)}=\frac{\partial(f,g)}{\partial(x,y)}\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(h,k)}=\frac{\partial(f,g)}{\partial(x,y)}\left(\frac{\partial(h,k)}{\partial(x,y)}\right)^{-1}$$

```
Clear["`*"];
a = {x1^2 + 5 + 6*x2, x1 - x2};
b = {x1^4 + x2, x1 + 4*x2^2};
D[a, {{x1, x2}}].Inverse[D[b, {{x1, x2}}]] // Simplify
% // MatrixForm
```

```
{{(6 - 16 x1 x2)/(1 - 32 x1^3 x2), (2 x1 - 24 x1^3)/(
  1 - 32 x1^3 x2)}, {(1 + 8 x2)/(-1 + 32 x1^3 x2), (1 + 4 x1^3)/(
  1 - 32 x1^3 x2)}}
```

I guess you want to calculate Jacobian Det instead of JacobianMatrix,isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

First: The Jacobian Matrix is defined for n scalar functions f1..fn of arguments x1..xn as:

{{D[f1[x1,..],x1],D[f1[x1,..],x2],..},

{D[f2[x1,..],x1],D[f2[x1,..],x2],..},   ..}

But your a and b are vector functions. So it is not clear what you want.

Lets assume that you have only a and want the Jacobian. This can be written as:

```
D[a,{{x1,x2}}]
(*{{2 x1, 6}, {1, -1}}*)
```

Likewise with b:

```
D[b, {{x1, x2}}]
(*{{4 x1^3, 1}, {1, 8 x2}}*)
```